# Close the dialog box using jquery

Tags: jquery

Trying to close the box using esc not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnShowSimple").click(function(e) {
        ShowDialog(false);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#btnShowModal").click(function(e) {
        ShowDialog(true);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#btnClose").click(function(e) {
        HideDialog();
        e.preventDefault();
    });



});

function ShowDialog(modal) {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);

    if (modal) {
        $("#overlay").unbind("click");
    }
    else {
        $("#overlay").click(function(e) {
            HideDialog();
        });
    }
}

function HideDialog() {
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
}


$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('.btnClose').click();
    } // esc
});​
```

Comment: Should that be `.btnClose` or `#btnClose` on keyup()?

Comment: Are you trying to use the `esc` key to close the modal? If so you need to listen for a keyup event.

Comment: worked by add hide dialog to the event

Comment: If it's a jquery-ui dialog box it closes automatically with esc?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just call your `HideDialog()` function?

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        HideDialog();
    } // esc
});​
```